# bootstraps nav bar 2 layers thick sometimes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

On my website https://garlandindustriesllc.com the bootstraps nav bar `<nav></nav>`
keeps becoming double thick. I'm not sure why. It only shows double thick sometimes and can be fixed by resizing the page window. 
[image: Double thick bar]

Most of the time it is correct with 1 row instead of 2.

[image: 1 row thick nav bar]

What is the problem? and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Post your html and any css you're using.

Comment: @vanburen. I thought it would be easier to just go to the live website rather than post huge blocks of html and css.

Comment: Not really and most of all once you fix your issue the question is useless going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have found the problem. I was getting ready to post the html as  [vanburen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5042683/vanburen) suggested. I found a stray dash at the end of the dropdown menu code.

```
<li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Graderworks <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                              <a href="https://garlandindustriesllc.com/index.php/pages/view/graderworks">Basic Information</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://garlandindustriesllc.com/index.php/pages/view/examples">Examples</a>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://garlandindustriesllc.com/index.php/pages/view/price">Price</a>

                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="https://garlandindustriesllc.com/index.php/pages/view/download">Download</a>

                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>-
```

Removed it and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your grid classes look like they aren't set to be big enough, so it's going to squeeze it all on the right.  Without code, I can't really help you any more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
        .navbar-collapse.collapse {
         display: inline!important;
}
```

into your custom.css file